# Is Seaory S22 card printer encoder compatible with Java Card

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I have a Seaory S22 card printer and it has a chip card reading and writing module. I can't reach the constructor so I want to know if it is compatible with Java Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Seaory S22 is compatible with Javacard, according to their website. You can find the manual [here](https://www.seaoryprinter.com/uploads/QuickUse/Seaory-S22-Card-Printer-Quick-User-Guide.pdf):

Since it supports CPU cards (ISO 7816, T=1 & T=0), it should be no problem on interaction with the smartcard in Javacard way. But I can't find an SDK on their website, make sure you could.